# What does SUM(var1 + var2) return?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was doing some grouping and tried the following:

```
declare @toErase table
(
    Group1 int,
    Num int,
    Denom int
)
insert into @toErase select 1, 1, 5
insert into @toErase select 1, 3, 36
insert into @toErase select 1, 4, null
insert into @toErase select 1, null, 15

select sum(num + denom) from @toErase group by group1

-- Returns 45
```

This returns 45. Where does the 45 come from?

On the other hand, `select sum(num) + sum(denom) from @toErase group by group1` returns the correct value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It comes from:

```
row1: 1+5 = 6
row2: 3+36 = 39
row3: 4+null = null
row4: null+15 = null
```

`SUM` ignores nulls, so the result is 6+39=45.

Use `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` to replace the nulls with a default value (probably 0) and thus effectively ignore them in the `+` operation as well.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of a not null value with a null one is null.

So both 4 + null and  null + 15 results in null and they are ignored by the `SUM`.

Answer (score 0):

You get `45` in your output since if you perform addition with `NULL` the result will be `NULL`, thus the result for operation on **third and fourth** row is `NULL` and is excluded from `sum()`.

If you wish to include such cases, then add `COALESCE()` on both columns to return `0` instead of `NULL` as arguments for addition operation:

```
select sum(coalesce(num,0) + coalesce(denom,0)) from @toErase group by group1
```

This would give you probably expected `64`.

Answer (score 0):

(1+5)   => 6

(3+36)  => 39

4+null  => null
note: NULL yields addition to be null

null+15 => null
note: NULL yields addition to be null

So 6+39 => 45
note: sum() ignores null

Answer (score 0):

If you do a SUM on a null and an integer, the result is null.

If you want to treat null as 0, you could always use the ISNULL command to default a null integer to be something else (my example replaces null with 0):

```
declare @toErase table
(
    Group1 int,
    Num int,
    Denom int
)
insert into @toErase select 1, 1, 5
insert into @toErase select 1, 3, 36
insert into @toErase select 1, 4, null
insert into @toErase select 1, null, 15

select sum(ISNULL(num,0) + ISNULL(denom,0)) from @toErase group by group1
```

This will return 64.

Answer (score 0):

Your SUM only keeps those two rows because of the NULL in your other rows column where you want to use SUM :

```
insert into @toErase select 1, 1, 5
insert into @toErase select 1, 3, 36
```

So you get : 1+5 + 36+3 = 45

Answer (score 0):

The result is because SUM ignores the null values, by example 4+null=null, so is not considered in the final sum.

```
1+5 = 6
3+36 = 39
4+null = null
null+15 = null
```

so, 6+39=45. Maybe COALESCE() can help you

You can try this:

SELECT SUM(COALESCE(num,0) + COALESCE(denom,0)) from @toErase GROUP BY group1